# PIMCore carousel issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, pimcore

I'm building a new website using PIMCore for the first time and getting to grips with it quite well. However, I've come across an issue which has me stumped and looking for an answer on google has proved fruitless.

I've added a block and then placed the gallery carousel feature in it, this works great. I can add an image, title and description to the first slide, however, all subsequent slides do not show any images nor the inputs for the title and description. You merely get two horizontal lines which I presume are the input boxes (see below).

[image]

Even if I code the carousel feature in myself, just leaving the image, title and description as input fields, it still comes out the same way. Looking at the demo suite on PIMCore 4, the front page carousel works as intended, however, in the basic-examples and galleries, it comes out as above, which to me signifies a major problem in the carousel code.

Any help would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In such cases it mostly makes sense to just disable the carousel plugin when in editmode and just display images one after another.

For example:

```
<script>
$('.carousel').carouselPlugin({
  ////////////
});
</script>

<div class="<?= $this->editmode?"carousel-editmode":"carousel" ?>">
  <?php // In editmode just display images one after another, or just use a multi-href field instead ?>
</div>
```

It would be hard and unreliable to make it working otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for that Igor. I just need to make sure that the resulting output is acceptable to our content managers in order to make any changes etc.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is closed, but I came up with the following solution which keeps the carousel intact in the pimcore admin:

in: website/views/areas/gallery-carousel/view.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.pimcore_editable .pimcore_tag_textarea').height(30);
    $('.pimcore_editable .pimcore_tag_input').height(30);
});
</script>
```